# How to get count of installments that customers paid or must paid in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get the count of installments that customers already paid for each bill and how many installments they should pay either they paid parts of the installments or they didn't. I tried this code but I couldn't get the real result either I get paid installments of bill or wrong counts of paid installments.

```
SELECT
  sb.op_id ,
  sb.auto_bill_no as sales_bill_no ,
  sb.installmnts_cont ,
  sb.installmnts_cont - COUNT(cupa.installment_no) as installmnts_net ,
  sb.bill_total
FROM sale_bill as sb
LEFT OUTER JOIN custmrs_paymnts as cupa ON
  sb.installmnt = 1 AND
  sb.installmnt_completed = 0 --AND sb.op_id = cupa.sales_bill_no
WHERE cupa.installment = 1
  AND sb.custmr_id = @cstmr_no
  AND cupa.custmr_id =     @cstmr_no
group by sb.op_id , sb.auto_bill_no , sb.installmnts_cont , sb.bill_total
```

Sample data from sale_bill table :

```
op_id    auto_bill_no   installmnts_cont installmnt_completed  bill_total
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
55           10               2              true                6000
56           11               2              false               4000
```

Sample data from custmrs_paymnts table :

```
money_amt         installment    sales_bill_no    installment_no
-----------------------------------------------------------------
3000                  true             55               1
3000                  true             55               2
```

The desired results are:

```
sales_bill_no    installmnts_cont   installmnts_net   bill_total
---------------------------------------------------------------------
55                    2                    0             6000
56                    2                    2             4000
```

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: I'm sorry but I couldn't formatting the question very well.

Answer (score 0):

I do see a problem with your join conditions.  Like there really aren't any.  I'm not sure if this will fix your problem but it is worth a try:

```
SELECT . . .
FROM sale_bill sb LEFT OUTER JOIN
     custmrs_paymnts cupa
     ON sb.custmr_id = cupa.custmr_id AND
        cupa.installment = 1
WHERE sb.custmr_id  = @cstmr_no AND
      sb.installmnt = 1 AND
      sb.installmnt_completed = 0
```

Some rules:

- Tables should normally be joined on columns in the tables, in the `ON` clause.
- Conditions on the first table of a `LEFT JOIN` should go in the `WHERE`.
- Conditions on the second table of a `LEFT JOIN` should go in the `ON`.

Comment: Thank u but it doesn't solve the problem especially when using Count function to get the difference of paid installments. what should I do now?

Comment: I want to know how many installments per bill the customer have paid or haven't paid yet.